# Input click area larger than input, causing buttons not to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Bootstrap to build a navbar using the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.review').on('click',function() {
  alert('test');
 })
})
```

```css
.navbar-light {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  z-index: 100000;
}

.navbar .row {
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-2" id="">
      <a class="" id=""><img src="img.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search for items" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 d-none d-sm-block review"><p>Test</p></div>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
<footer>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

However, utilising this code causes any attempts to click the `.review` class to actually select the `input` field. It appears as though the input fields clickable area extends beyond the end of its physical element.

I am looking for a way to get the button to the right of the element (`.review`) clickable, whilst allow users to click on the `input` field - but only within its physical area.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome. When I click on the 'Test', I get the alert 'test'

Comment: It works fine for me, but you can try to put the click function on the input and p elements themselves instead of their div's this way it shouldn't be going out of boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the click event from bubbling to parent elements using `event.stopPropagation()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.review').on('click',function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
        alert('test');
    })
})
```